# Convert an attribute to its name

Tags: java

It is possible to access a class attribute by its name using the following code:

```
MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("myAtt");
```

is it possible to create a function which do reverse? i.e. a function which convert an attribute to its name?

**EDIT:** I'm adding this edit to make this more clear:
consider the following class:

```
class MyClass {
    Integer myAttribute;
}
```

I am looking for a function which accepts `myAttribute` (itself, or a reference to it. idk!) and returns `"myAttribute"` string.

Comment: What do you mean by "...convert an attribute to its name..."? That doesn't immediately seem to make sense.

Comment: Are you searching for Field.getName()??

Comment: the above function's input is an `String` and the output is the attribute. I'm looking for a function which do reverse. i.e. gets an attribute as input (lack of references I'm not quite sure what this means in Java but it has meaning in C++) and return its name. e.g.
`MyFunc(myAtt)` should return `"myAtt"`.

Comment: something like[`Field.getName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName())?

Comment: @RohitJain if you convert an attribute to a Field first, then yes!

Comment: @JanDvorak yes, but can I convert an attribute to Field?

Comment: @AsgharKopak What exactly are you referring the attributes to?? You can get all the `Declared Fields` of a class. Then get their names.

Comment: @AsgharKopak: *"if you convert an attribute to a Field first, then yes!"* Based on your code snippet above, what you're calling an "attribute" **is** a field.

Comment: @AsgharKopak In what form are you having your what so called attribute? Can you provide the definition of attribute that is in your mind? Or an example

Comment: by Field I mean `java.lang.reflect.Field` Class. By attribute I mean a simple class attribute:
`class MyClass { String myAttribute; }`

Comment: So given a value, you want to find out the name of the Field that contains that value?

Comment: I edited the question. that might help a little bit.

Comment: @AsgharKopak Ok, now your question doesn't make sense.. You actaully want to get `Field` object for given attribute name,. and then fetch back the field name from that object..

Comment: @AsgharKopak Why on earth would you want to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Try `java.lang.reflect.Field.getName();`

Comment: this requires me to convert an attribute to its corresponding Field first. How can I do that?

Comment: @AsgharKopak: What do you mean by "convert"? The sentence makes no sense. Rather than reiterating things that aren't clear, try creating an actual concrete example in code, showing **exactly** what you want to provide as an input to your function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Field#getName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Field.html#getName%28%29) method : -

```
Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();

for (Field field: fields) {
    System.out.println(field.getName());
}
```

**PS**: - You should name your classes starting with `uppercase` letters.

**UPDATE**: -  Ok, if you have your name of the attribute: - `private String attrName;`, you can get the corresponding field my using: -

```
Field field = MyClass.class.getDeclaredField("attrName");

// Then do this. Which is meaningless. But I don't know why you want to do this
// Your fieldName will contain "attrName" which you know already
String fieldName = field.getName();
```

But fetching the name from the above field doesn't make sense. I would be surprised if you were looking for this only. But you can be more clear with your question.

Comment: this is converting __ALL__ the attributes. I'm looking for a way to convert an specific attribute.

Comment: @AsgharKopak Do you have a name for your attribute?? And this is not the reason to downvote as you are not very clear with your question..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question you want to get the name of the Field thats current value matches the value of a variable.

```
private String getAttributeName(Object myInstance, Object myValue) throws IllegalAccessException
{
    Field[] fields = MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field each : fields)
    {
        if (each.get(myInstance).equals(myValue))
            return each.getName();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Then you can call it,

```
    getAttributeName(myInstance, myValue);
```